# Rename txt files based on the file's content (OSX)

Tags: macos, terminal, batch, rename

I have about 250 txt files that are all named link.txt and they have this information always on the line/row 3:

> title: Some kind of title

I need some kind of script that can go through these files, grab the title and put it as the filename. The folder structure is: 1-links/20150528/1/ so would be great if I could just run the script in "1-links" and it would start looking for files named "link.txt".

I'm using Mac OSX.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
for i in `find . -name link.txt -type f`;
do
nn=$(sed -n -e 3p -e "s/title:\ // "$i")
mv "$i" "`dirname $i`/$nn"
done
```

If you want to rename last directory in the path instead of file you can use something like:

```
for i in `find . -name link.txt -type f`;
do
nn=$(sed  -n -e 's/title: //'  -e 3p $i)
odir=`dirname $i`
ndir=$(echo $odir|awk -v nn="$nn" -F\/ 'BEGIN {OFS="/"}  {$NF=nn;print}')
mv  "$odir" "$ndir"
done
```

Comment: Can I just paste this to terminal or how do I run this?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to run it. Would it be hard to modify this script so that instead of renaming the link.txt it would rename the parent folder? So in my previous example case the folder named "1".

Comment: Do you mean to rename 1/link.txt to become (for example) name/link.txt?

Comment: Yes exactly like that.

Comment: See my edited answer. BTW it is not tested

Comment: I get this message: awk: can't open file the
 source line number 1
./rename.sh: line 4: echo: write error: Broken pipe
mv: rename ./1-links/20150528/5 to : No such file or directory

Comment: Answer edited and a little bit of code clean :)